# Surface Pro 4 UEFI Password reset

Tags: uefi, microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro-4

I have a Surface Pro 4 in which I have never set a `UEFI` password , but today when I tried to enter `UEFI` it is promoting me to enter a password which I have never set. I bought it brand new so I am pretty sure no one else had set a password in UEFI.

I know in normal PCs we can just remove `CMOS` to reset the password of BIOS but how am I suppose to go with resetting a UEFI password for Surface Pro 4 ?, is there any possible way to do this ? Or is there a default BIOS password on Surface Pro 4 which I am not aware of ? (I tried searching but couldn't find any resources that says there is a default UEFI password).

**Edit:** This user shows how to remove the battery of Surface Pro 4, but its sounds like a horrible idea, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrDPOkFoyXI 
Is this the only option I have beside taking it to Microsoft store ?

Also, according to [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-au/support/warranty-service-and-recovery/how-to-use-the-bios-uefi-with-surface-book-and-surface-pro-4),

> You cannot reset your UEFI password, and Microsoft cannot retrieve it.

Kindly help.

Comment: I would asssume that Microsoft is correct.

Comment: Have you tried to just press enter (if the password is empty)?

Comment: i have same problem with surface book
my problem is i remember what i tapped, but i remember i tapped it on virtual AZERTY keyboard
i never get to have that any more
i retaped the same with QWERTY (virtual ou physical) and AZERTY phisical